# I found a span on a website that is not visible and I can't scrape it! Why?

Tags: python, selenium

Currently I'm trying to scrape data from a website. Therefore I'm using Selenium.
Everything is working as it should. Until I realised I have to scrape a tooltiptext.

I found already different threads on stackoverflow that are providing an answer. Anyway I did not manage to solve this issue so far.

After a few hours of frustration I realised the following:
[image]

This span has nothing to do with the tooltip I guess. Because the tooltip looks like this:
[image]

There is actually a span that I can't read. I try to read it like this:

```
bewertung = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="a-icon-alt"]')
for item in bewertung:
    print(item.text)
```

So Selenium finds this element. But unfortunatly '.text' returns nothing. Why is it always empty ?
And what for is the span from the first screenshot ? Btw. it is not displayed at the Website as well.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: maybe try by getting the innerHTML instead.   So try with item.get_attribute('innerHTML')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've mentioned `Selenium finds this element`, I would assume you must have print the `len` of `bewertung` **list**

something like

```
print(len(bewertung))
```

if this list has some element in it, you could probably use `innerText`

```
bewertung = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="a-icon-alt"]')
for item in bewertung:
    print(item.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

Note that, you are using `find_elements` which won't throw any error instead if it does not find the `element` it will return an `empty list`.

so if you use `find_element` instead, it would throw the exact error.

Also, I think you've `xpath` for the span (Which does not appear in UI, sometime they don't appear until some actions are triggered.)

You can try to use this `xpath` instead:

```
//i[@data-hook='average-stars-rating-anywhere']//span[@data-hook='acr-average-stars-rating-text']
```

Something like this in code:

```
bewertung = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//i[@data-hook='average-stars-rating-anywhere']//span[@data-hook='acr-average-stars-rating-text']")
    for item in bewertung:
        print(item.text)
```